# PhpStorm incorrectly showing files as unversioned in Git

Tags: git, phpstorm, git-untracked, phpstorm-2018.1

In a project I have that is under Git PhpStorm is showing a bunch of files that it states are "unversioned", however Git disagrees.

Running:

```
git ls-files . --exclude-standard --others
```

...from the *Terminal* shows nothing.

PhpStorm version **2018.1.6**

Did PhpStorm get confused somehow or what is the problem here?

Comment: I would suggest you ask this one here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/. Seems to me that you just might've stumbled upon something that shouldn't work the way it does. However, I've had no issues with git in PhpStorm and am currently using the same version.

Comment: @rkeet Yeah, it's usually fine for me, so I'm assuming something got messed up somewhere, just unsure what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems I had previously set this project to using the *SubVersion* VCS.

I fixed this by:

- Pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> (Windows) to bring up *Settings*
- Navigating to *Version Control*
- On the right I saw my project and changed the and changed the selection under the *VCS* header to "Git"

After I had done this it started working correctly.

Comment: As git is installed separately (Windows) from PhpStorm (which uses it), and as git version control is stored in `.git` folder within project, any idea as to how a Terminal command from Git gets confused by PhpStorm? Does sound like a bug...

Comment: @rkeet The terminal within PhpStorm was working correctly even when on SubVersion.

Comment: Oh my bad, remembered the question the wrong way around from the other day ;-)